# Facing issues in calling one js file from another file in node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Beginner In react js.I am trying to access one js file in another js file.I am using the concept of node custom module.I am tring to access this two different files.I export file in Utility.js and import this file    in app.js.It is working fine.But when i want to access SecurityUtil.js, it is showing error Util has been already declared.Help me to solve this issues?

```
I created two different Files
1.Utility.js [Present in Utility folder]
2.SecurityUtil.js

Utility.js
=========
//lets define an arrow function

let greet = (name) => {
    console.log(`welcome to Node js Learning path, ${name}.`)
};
//To make available this function to another file we need to export this js file.
module.exports = {
    greet
};

SecurityUtil.js
===============
//Here we are declaring some security method
//We want to call this function from app.js.Before calling it we need to export it and import in app.js


let securityConfig = () => {
    return "This is a Security config File";
};

//export the file
module.exports = {
 securityConfig
};

app.js
======
//here we need to import the file in app.js to use it
const Util = require('./Util/Utility');
const Util = require('./Util/SecurityUtil');



//here we can call custom module function


Util.greet("Kabir");
Util.securityConfig();
```

> Can anybody help me here as i am beginner in learning React js and
> Node js?

Answer (score 0):

In `app.js`, you are doing:

```
const Util = require('./Util/Utility');
const Util = require('./Util/SecurityUtil');
```

This is wrong. You cannot [re-declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) a `const` which is already declared. Change it to:

```
const util = require('./Util/Utility');
const securityUtil = require('./Util/SecurityUtil');

// Here we can call custom module function


util.greet("Kabir");
securityUtil.securityConfig();
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing a function into the app.js file you should destructure like so:

```
const {greet} = require("./Util/Utility");
```

Since you're using reactjs, it's recommended to use newer syntax

```
import {greet} from "./Util/Utility"
```